# Some fields are empty after deserialization in Silverlight project

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization, deserialization

I have a problem with deserialization in my silverlight project. I have class Obj with this methods and variables.

```
public class Obj
{
    private string _name;
    private Uri _iconUri;
    private string _stringUri;
    private List<ObjItem> _items = new List<ObjItem>();

    public List<ObjItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return _name; } 
        set { _name = value; } 
    }
    public Uri IconUri 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _iconUri; 
        } 
    }
    public string StringUri { get { return _stringUri; } }
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _items.Count; }
    }

    public Obj(string name,string uriString = null)
    {
        _name = name;
        if (uriString == null)
        {
            _iconUri = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _iconUri = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        _stringUri = uriString;
    }
    // for deserialization
    public Obj()
    {
    }
```

}

Before serialization all fields are not empty!
After deserialization all fields are not empry except _iconUri and _stringUri fields.
Why is it happened?
I'll be waiting for your replies.
Thank you!

Comment: because Uri class is not serializable, I guess, which serialization are you using? change the type to string, and keep another property that converts and returns Uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two don't have setters. Silverlight has a restricted security model, where you cant can't cheat by accessing private fields; only public members can be accessed. So: add public setters to those properties if you want them to work with most serializers on SL.

To be specific: _name is being set by the Name setter, and _items is being set in the constructor via the field-initializer.